# How to validate email id for UTF -8 characters

Tags: android

email id validation in Android for  multi language characters
Hi 
I need to validate a email id. I am typing characters in other language before @ symbol and after @ symbol I am typing as gmail.com.
How to validate the above email id

my email id : 闪闪发光@x.com
I used the following  method : 
android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches(); 
I am getting the value as false.

how to validate the above email.

Answer (score 0):

String regex = "^[\p{L}A-Z0-9a-z.*'-]+@"+"[\p{L}A-Za-z0-9.*'-]+\.[\p{L}A-Za-z]{2,3}"; 
or

"^[\p{L}_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[\p{L}_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[\p{L}A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[\p{L}A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[\p{L}A-Za-z]{2,})$";

http://www.sw-engineering-candies.com/blog-1/howtofindvalidemailaddresswitharegularexpressionregexinjava

Comment: The link is now broken.